# Let $\def\*#1{\mathbf{#1}}\*{u},\*{v},\*{w}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be noncollinear. Show that $\*{x}= r\*{u}+s\*{v}+t\*{w}$ where $r+s+t=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are noncollinear points $\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that we can write $\mathbf{x}$ uniquely in the form $\mathbf{x} = r\mathbf{u}+s\mathbf{v}+t\mathbf{w}$ where $r+s+t=1$.

Textbook (Shifrin's Multivariable Mathematics) hint (paraphrased):

$\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{u} \nparallel \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u}$ so, $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{w}-\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u}\end{bmatrix}$ is an invertible $2\times2$ matrix.

---

Attempt:

Let $\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{w}-\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u}\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{A}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{x}$.

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{x}) \\
&= \mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{c} \\
&= (\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{u})\times c_1 + (\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u})\times c_2 \\
&= c_1\mathbf{w} + (-c_1-c_2)\mathbf{u} + c_2\mathbf{v}
\end{align}
$$

Regrettably, $c_1 + (-c_1-c_2) + c_2 = 0 \neq 1$.

---

Questions:

1. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @copper.hat, good catch. $\mathbf{x}$ is an arbitrary vector $\in\mathbb{R}^2$. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $x$ there is a unique $c$ such that
$x-u = c_1 (w-u)+c_2(v-u)$.

In other words,
$x = c_1 w + c_2 v + (1-c_1-c_2) u$.

Answer (score 2):

You've found a representation of $\mathbf x$ where the coefficients of $\mathbf u, \mathbf v, \mathbf w$ add to $0$. That doesn't do *everything* you want, but it is a good first step.

Can you find a representation of $\mathbf 0$ in which the coefficients of $\mathbf u, \mathbf v, \mathbf w$ add to $1$? If so, then you could combine those, and get a representation of $\mathbf x + \mathbf 0$ in which the coefficients add to $0+1$.

Comment: +1. I really like your suggestion as I can see that this should have been  the next logical question I ask myself. I got stuck trying to literally solve the equation $\mathbf{u} = c_1\mathbf{w} + (-c_1-c_2)\mathbf{u}+c_2\mathbf{v}$ and manually setting $-c_1-c_2$ to 1 and solving for the remaining values when I should have just done what @copper.hat did.